# I need help programming an isometric pathfinding Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, isometric

I'm making a game with Isometric Tilemap Using this Grid Configs:
Cell Size: X: 0.32 Y: 0.16 Z: 0.32
Cell Layout: Isometric Z as Y
Cell Swizzle: XYZ

I have created a movement that works perfectly for the character, but I need to create the movement of an NPC to a specific point.

I created a very simple movement that checks the available nearby tiles and checks which one is closest to the point.
However it is not an intelligent movement, because it can have problems with walls and the fastest way would be in zigzag.
I attach here the zigzag image and another image of the way I want it to go.

I can get the center points of the available tiles and save them, but after that I don't know how to proceed and I need help to make a NPC movement code.

[ZigZag Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQo01.png)

[Expectation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k98ET.png)

Comment: How path-finding works in a grid is irrelevant to how you're rendering that grid. The approach used for an isometrically-rendered grid is the same for a face-on square-grid or a perspective-rendered grid.

Comment: What is the question here anyway? You say the fastest way is a zig zag but it's "not an intelligent movement"?

Comment: I want to make a NPC movement and normal or A* pathfinding always results in problems because of isometry